# Xcode 6.4 crashes on exporting an archive for Enterprise Deployment. "teamID should be a non-empty string, but it is nil"

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to export my Enterprise ipa for test. Archive is OK. But when I select 'Use local signing assets' and click "Choose", Xcode crashes.
When I use jenkins for export Enterprise ipa, I can export ipa successful, but the app always crash when startup on ios.
I use another mac which installed the same XCode(same version), I can export the ipa, and everything is OK.
I delete the XCode 6.4, and reinstall Xcode 6.4 again, but still crashes.
What's wrong with my mac?

[exporting an archive for Enterprise Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Viugi.png)

```
Process:               Xcode [71424]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.4 (7720)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7720000000000000~8
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [71424]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-18 10:44:49.695 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        62929F33-AB7D-0C0E-F891-012B8C26B488

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B87FC6FF-87B4-4596-99C5-3CFB366D732A

Time Awake Since Boot: 65000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6E35b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7720/IDEFoundation/Distribution/IDEDistributionProvisioning.m:37
Details:  teamID should be a non-empty string, but it is nil
Object:   <IDEDistributionProvisioning: 0x7fb110a2eaf0>
Method:   -initWithRootDistributionItems:distributionMethod:teamID:codesignableDevicesOrNil:logging:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb10a641260>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010f727fda -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010e47265f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010e47294e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010ef1946c -[IDEDistributionProvisioning initWithRootDistributionItems:distributionMethod:teamID:codesignableDevicesOrNil:logging:] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x000000010f9bbe76 __75-[IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStepViewController _locateSigningAssetsAsync]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00007fff9d3e8323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6  0x00007fff9d3e3c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff9d3efcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff9616b3f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff9612668f __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff96125bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 11  0x00007fff95b4d56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 12  0x00007fff95b4d2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 13  0x00007fff95b4d12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 14  0x00007fff924f68ab _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 15  0x00007fff924f5e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 16  0x000000010e9f6aaa -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 17  0x00007fff924ebaf3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff92468244 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff91e7e5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 20  0x0000000000000001

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
(teamID) != nil

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9b8f5286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff95a909b3 abort + 129
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f727bc3 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1507
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f728190 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1169
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e47265f _DVTAssertionHandler + 367
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e47294e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010ef1946c -[IDEDistributionProvisioning initWithRootDistributionItems:distributionMethod:teamID:codesignableDevicesOrNil:logging:] + 908
7   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f9bbe76 __75-[IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStepViewController _locateSigningAssetsAsync]_block_invoke + 1717
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9d3e8323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9d3e3c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9d3efcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9616b3f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
```

Answer (score 0):

That issue was bothering me for a while and I never noticed the "teamID should be a non-empty string, but it is nil".

What partially solved my issue is making sure I have a team selected here in the target configuration.

My thought process is that I don't use signing before distribution and I didn't think I needed it but well...

After that new builds that you do no longer crashes Xcode.

Mine crashed when I was trying to download the dSYMs symbols, so it's a bit different than what you're doing but it might help.

[image: Build settings for a target]